# ASP.NET MVC Controller cannot return HttpResponseMessage correctly with streamed content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Just as the title says I am not getting the MVC Controller to return HttpResponseMessage correctly.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDataAsJsonStream()
    {
        object returnObj = new
        {
            Name = "Alice",
            Age = 23,
            Pets = new List<string> { "Fido", "Polly", "Spot" }
        };

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new MemoryStream().SerializeJson(returnObj);
        stream.Position = 0;
        response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        return response;
    }
```

This is what I got using MVC Controller:

[image: Incorrect result]

It works fine when using WebApi ApiController

[image: Correct result]

Correct me if I'm wrong I think the problem is MVC is serializing HttpResponseMessage instead of returning it.

By the way I am using MVC 5.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I would like to have the flexibility to write to the response stream directly when returning large datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Phil I got it to work by having the MVC controller return FileStreamResult.

Here is the code

```
    public ActionResult GetDataAsJsonStream()
    {
        object returnObj = new
        {
            Name = "Alice",
            Age = 23,
            Pets = new List<string> { "Fido", "Polly", "Spot" }
        };

        var stream = new MemoryStream().SerializeJson(returnObj);
        stream.Position = 0;

        return File(stream, "application/json");
    }
```

**UPDATE**

A better way to do this is to write directly to the response stream without creating a memory stream

```
    public ActionResult GetJsonStreamWrittenToResponseStream()
    {
        object returnObj = new
        {
            Name = "Alice",
            Age = 23,
            Pets = new List<string> { "Fido", "Polly", "Spot" }
        };

        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Response.OutputStream.SerializeJson(returnObj);

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps try returning an `ActionResult` from your MVC method instead.

```
public ActionResult GetDataAsJsonStream() {}
```

In order to return a stream, you'll likely have to use `FileStreamResult`.  What would be even easier is just returning a `JsonResult`.

```
public ActionResult GetDataAsJson()
{
    object returnObj = new
    {
        Name = "Alice",
        Age = 23,
        Pets = new List<string> { "Fido", "Polly", "Spot" }
    };

    return Json(returnObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is pseudo code but the concept should be sound.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I am aware of the Json() controller method. What I am concerned is when returning large datasets. Json() will first serialize into Json objects in memory before writing it out to the response stream. I like to  write to the stream directly so it won't eat up memory.

Comment: @superfly71 if that's the case and it's probably something you should have mentioned in your question, you could probably use `FileStreamResult` with a contentType of 'application/json'.

Comment: @superfly71 nice :) that will definitely give some context around this when someone stumbles upon this question in the not so distant future.