# ASP.NET MVC Large file download using HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpclient, large-files

I referred many post, still unable to get a solution. I need to download file from REST endpoint without causing Out of Memory. Below is the code, I have used

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadFile()
    {

        var client = StorageClientFactory<RestModel>.
            CreateRESTClient("https://bigfile-test.restsite.net");   //creates httpclient object

        var strm = await client.DownloadFileAsResponse("/300mb.zip");   //gets the stream using await GetStreamAsync("rest/300mb.zip")

        var res = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(strm)
        };

        res.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        res.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        { FileName = "300mb.zip" };

        return res;
```

HTML

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="File1" name="file" multiple />
        <button type="submit" formaction="/Default/UploadFile" name="btnUpload" value="UploadFile" formmethod="post">
            Upload
        </button>
        <label>@ViewBag.Result</label>  
        <button type="submit" formaction="/Default/DownloadFile" name="btnDownload" value="DownloadFile">
            Download
        </button>                     
    </form>
```

When I click the download button all I get is success response. But file is not downloaded. Not sure why.

StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=300mb.zip }

Comment: Why don't you use a FileStreamResult instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964330/asp-net-mvc-controller-cannot-return-httpresponsemessage-correctly-with-streamed/37991563

Comment: @ArneKlein I found the mistake, I should have run the code in WebApi controller not MVC controller.